# Powershell attachment sending

Tags: powershell, email, cmd, smtp, attachment

I need help guys.

This command doesn't work for me because

> The system cannot find the file specified.

```
powershell -command "& { Send-MailMessage -From "janohanes155 <janohanes155@gmail.com>" -To "janohanes155 <janohanes155@gmail.com>" -Subject "Sending the Attachment" -Body "Got it" -Attachments "c:\shade\info.txt" -Priority High -dno onSuccess, onFailure -SmtpServer "smtp.gmail.com" -Credential "********/*********"}"
```

What should I do?

Thank you for help.

Comment: Would you mind copying and pasting the exact error message into the question. You know it must be asked, are you sure that "C:\shade\info.txt" exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your double-quoted string contains ***embedded* `"` chars. that you *forgot to escape***.

Additionally, since there are **potentially *2* layers of escapin**g - one for the *current shell* and one for the *target* shell, ***additional escaping* may be needed**.

The **specific method of escaping depends on where you're invoking the command *from*.**

The following examples use a simplified command that more succinctly demonstrates the problem; in pure PowerShell form, the command is:
`Write-Output "jdoe <jdoe@example.com>"`

The curious thing is that **when PowerShell is passed a `-Command` value *from the outside*, it requires embedded `"` chars. to be `\`-escaped**, while **PowerShell-*internally* `` ` ``-escaping must be used**.

---

**From the Windows Run dialog** (<kbd>Win+R</kbd>):

All that is needed is to `\`-escape the embedded `"` chars., for the benefit of the target PowerShell instance (no *current* shell is involved):

```
powershell -command "& { Write-Output \"jdoe <jdoe@example.com>\" }"
```

---

**From `cmd.exe` (Command Prompt)**:

```
powershell -command "& { Write-Output \"jdoe ^<jdoe@example.com^>\" }"
```

In addition to `\`-escaping `"`, you must also `^`-escape `<` and `>` characters that `cmd.exe` *thinks* are *outside* of a double-quoted string, due to not  recognizing `\`-escaped `"` chars. as escaped (`cmd.exe` only recognizes `""`).

It is the unintended interpretation of `<` and `>` as *shell redirection operators* by `cmd.exe` that caused the error message you've encountered.

---

**From PowerShell** itself:

```
powershell -command "& { Write-Output \`"jdoe <jdoe@example.com>\`" }"
```

In addition to `\`-escaping `"` for the *target* PowerShell instance, you must also `` ` ``-escape `"` chars. for the *current* PowerShell instance (sic).

Comment: Thank you, it helped me a lot.